# iOS application crashes when message send to a number detected via DataDetector in UITextview

Tags: ios, uitextview, datadetectortypes

I have a Uitextview with Datadetector enabled in UItableViewCell.Uitextview successfully detects phone number,email etc,but when tried to send message to phone number detected,app crashes.

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: @almas i think crashes is related to dismissing in ModelView Controller.Since MessageComposeView Controller is presented modally once we tap on email/no detected.